# How to use structs, typedef, and template?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I'm trying to implement the following code, but I keep getting an error because of `typedef`, can someone please help?

```
 template<class T>
 struct box{
 T data;
 box *link;
 };
 typedef box* boxPtr;
```

the error is:

```
Use of class template 'box' requires template arguments
```

Comment: Please add the error message as well.

Comment: It's a short snippet, but there is still a fair bit to unpack here. You may be better served by choosing and working through one of the books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: an answer to your title can fill several chapters of a book. Please try to be more specific. What exactly do you want to achieve? And what is the error?

Comment: ok, now, what part of the error message do you not understand? `box` is a template, not a type

Comment: Just remove the typedef.

Comment: I don't understand how I would fix it, I've tried typedef<T>... but still the same

Comment: what is the aim? You want to declare a pointer to a box that has what type as data member?

Comment: or do you want a template alias? Ie a template that you can instantitate to get the type of  pointers to different `box` instantiations?

Comment: what type should that box have as member? `T` is just a place holder that only existst in the template. To get a concrete pointer you need to choose what `T` should be

Comment: if I remove typdfef, how can I in a class say define boxPtr as a type?

Comment: @harry Just don't define boxPtr as a type. You don't need it. Problem solved.

Comment: Side note: Usually a type alias is used to reduce the amount of typing necessary (`boxPtr<T>` longer than `box<T>*`) or to simplify and clarify (`boxPtr<T>` is no clearer than  `box<T>*`) I don't see any gain from `boxPtr`.

Comment: you dont want `box` to hold data of arbitrary type? do you? From some of your comments I get the impression that you confuse templates with javas generics, which is a completely different story. I might be completely wrong, tough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box` is a class template. This means that it needs an argument whenever you instantiate it:

```
box<int>   integerBox;
box<float> floatBox;
// etc
```

This is required anywhere you try to use a template class such as `box`. So a pointer to just a `box` doesn't make sense. It needs a type with it. For example:

```
template <class type>
using boxptr = box<type>*;
```

This does effectively the same thing as your typedef, but it allows you to specify he underlying template type.

Of course, if you do it this way, you will always need to specify a type when you use the pointer version:

```
boxptr<int>   integerBoxPtr;
boxptr<float> floatBoxPtr;
// etc
```

Comment: @harry You're welcome. Please note that on this site, the best way to thank someone is to up-vote their answer and/or accept it. We try to avoid comments in general on this site except when absolutely necessary. Thank you comments are usually not considered absolutely necessary--again we usually prefer you to up-vote and accept the best answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Writing

```
template<class T>
struct box{
    T data;
    box *link;
 
    typedef box<T>* boxPtr; 
};
```

with

```
int main()
{
    box<int>::boxPtr use_of_a_bad_idea;
}
```

is one way, but having pointer types masquerading as object types is a recipe for memory leaks: don't do it as a rule of thumb. *That's* the best way of addressing this problem.

Comment: *"having pointer types masquerading as pointer types"* - Ah... um...

Comment: Not  so long ago, I misread a question and wrote it off as a trivial matter of pass by value where pass by reference was required because the asker used a typedef to conceal that the type *was* a pointer. I could have just as easily given bad advice if I hadn't read through the code several times. the `Ptr` in `boxPtr` makes the pointer orders of magnitude more obvious than the other lost question, but still not as obvious as `box *` for anyone who's brain is conditioned to look for the `*`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Had a delivery today which required an excavator to make lots of turns over my once-pristine lawn. It now looks like a MOD training ground. Very stressful indeed. Hence the odd mistake or two creeping in.

Answer (score 1):

Use `using`:

```
template<class T>
struct box
{
    T data;
    box *link;
};

template <typename T>
using boxPtr = box<T>*;
```

Now `boxPtr<int>` is the same as `box<int>*`.

Answer (score 0):

This will compile:

```
template<class T>
struct Box {
    T data;
    Box<T> *link;
};

typedef Box<int> * BoxPTR;
```

Comment: I recommend you highlight or clarify the difference between your code and the OP's.

Comment: Remember that compiling is typically only the beginning.